# load Imge from my server error android studio

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to load some images from my server to New App, but i don't have any result :

This is my `MainActivity` code :

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import static android.net.Uri.parse;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        private ImageView iv;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new DownloadImageTask((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.loadimg)).execute(getString(R.string.link));              

          private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

            private final ImageView bmImage;
            ImageView bmImg;
            public DownloadImageTask (ImageView bmImage){
                this.bmImage=bmImage;
            }
            protected Bitmap doInBackground (String...urls){
                String underplay = urls[0];
                Bitmap mIcon11 =null;
                try {
                    InputStream in =new java.net.URL(underplay).openStream();
                    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return mIcon11 ;
            }
        }
```

The Result in emulator is not appear any thing just my Button ?

Comment: I don't have any result

Comment: You would help yourself by using Picasso to load your images. Mind you, your code lacks onPreExecute and onPosrExecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file under app:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
}
```

Then in your code you can simply load a bitmap or image from a server like so:

```
Picasso.with(this)
    .load(IMAGE_URL)
    .into(yourImageView);
```

Where `this` is the activity context. `IMAGE_URL` is the url of the image, example: `http://yourapi.com/image_1034.png`, and `yourImageView` is the `ImageView`, `ImageButton`, or other Custom View where you want to upload the image into.

Doing it this way is considered best practice, and reduces a lot of the boilerplate code you've written. Try building a scalable app writing AsyncTasks for every time you upload a `Bitmap`.

Comment: Dear can I use picasso to import many image and switch between them using finger move ?

Comment: Sure it's very versatile, just use an adapter with Picasso

Answer (score 1):

In your `AsyncTask` you need to implement:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap icon) {
  iv.setImageBitmap(icon)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code?

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```